# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins: invalid target release: 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

When I try load java kod from github to Heroku I have this error : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project curtainRod: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17.

My  mvn --version is
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (...)
Maven home: C:\A_\Java\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 17.0.6, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17

plase help to solve this problem
Grzegorz :-)

my pom.xml

I change my java version from 16 to 17 and add to pom.xml plugin  org.apache.maven.plugins

Heroku support java version 17.0.6

but I still have this problem, place help to solve this